# Printing values of UITextField to NSLog

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Textfield, and when i print its text to a `NSLog`, i get the output as `(null)`. I want to detect this how can i do this programatically.

I have tried several approaches and all of the following failed.

```
NSLog (@"Print %@ ", textfield.text);

if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:@""]) {}

if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {}

if ([textfield.text isEqualToString:nil]) {}
```

How can i detect `(null)` which is returned when printed using `NSLog` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
if (textfield.text == nil)
{
    NSLog( @"textfield is nil");
} else {
    if( [textfield.text length] == 0 )
    {
        NSLog( @"textfield has zero length")
    } else {
       NSLog( @"textfield is %@", textfield.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using

```
If([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    //Your code ....
}
```

or you can do it with

```
if(textField.text == Nil)
{
    //Your code ....
}
```

third option is that

```
if([textField.text length] == 0)
{
    //Your code ....
}
```

Comment: The 1st 2 doesn't work, but the 3rd one did the trick. Thank you